# how to read only specific coulmns from external tab delimited files using proc import into sas dataset

Tags: sas

is it possible to read only specific variabiles from text files into sas as sas dataset using proc import? I have very big data in my text file which contains like 1000 observations and more than 42,000 variables. I tried reading this file into sas using proc import  but i failed in doing so i thought may be because of size issues. Now i decided to read only specific variables (columns) really i do not need all of them from this big text file so that i can reduce size of file to read into sas system. is there any ideas to read like this by using data step? Suggestion or help would be appreciated

Thanking you very much,

Comment: Which version of sas are you using?

Comment: That must be an enormous text file.

Comment: 42k variables = 8 bytes per, let's say = 350kb per observation; so 350MB or so.  Not that enormous... but also probably not very well organized (not that i'm surprised, the stat world does a terrible job of thinking about data management for the most part).

Comment: i am using sas 9.2 version

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a delimited text file, you can read in specific variables, contingent on them being consecutive from the first variable.  You can't use PROC IMPORT to do this, however; you'd have to write the datastep yourself, though you could conceivably have PROC IMPORT help you write it.

For example, if you have 10 variables and only want the first 3, then you can read it in like this:

```
data want;
infile "mydata.txt" dlm=',' lrecl=255 missover dsd;
input x $ y $ z $;
run;
```

However, you must read in all variables from the first variable to the last variable you are interested in, even if you aren't interested in all of the intermediate variables.  You can't "skip" them with a delimited text file.

If you have a fixed width text file, you can read in whatever columns you want (but you can't use PROC IMPORT to read in a fixed width text file).

Comment: Dear Joe thank you very much for your help, i can not use input  statement because my file contains 42K variables, i tried like this  proc import datafile="file.txt" out=mydata dbms=tab replace; getnames=yes; run; then my system is freezing, my system config is 120gb HDD, 2gb RAM. can you please correct where i am doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to use the input statement whether you like to or not - that may simply be too many variables.  Can you update the original post with a little bit of information, such as: what kind of variables you have (all/mostly numeric, all/mostly character, mixed), how many variables you actually want, which ones you want by position (_not_ by name, ie, '3rd, 5th, 18th, and 250th variable')?